# Checkbox not checking when state updates react redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, input, checkbox, updates, redux-toolkit

I am trying to filter products when input checkbox clicked. It works but checkbox not checking.

I tried figure it out and found that at the end of reducer function "state.category = [...filtered.options]" line somehow prevents checkbox natural behavior. Any idea how to fix it?

This is reducer function--

```
setFilteredCategory: (state, action) => {
  const newFilter = action.payload;

  state.selectedFilters = { ...state.selectedFilters, ...newFilter };
  let values = Object.values(state.selectedFilters);

  let filteredProds = [] || null;

  state.categoryFilter.map((product) => {
    product.attributes.map((attributes) => {
      attributes.items.map((item) => {
        values.includes(item.value) && !filteredProds.includes(product)
          ? (filteredProds = [...filteredProds, product])
          : null;
      });
    });
  });

  state.category = [...filteredProds];
},
```

This is JSX ---

```
  <form key={item} className={styles.yesNo}>
              <label htmlFor="abc">
                {item}
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => this.handleFilterClick(e, key, item)}
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                <span className={styles.checkBox}></span>
              </label>
            </form>
enter code here
```

Comment: please add code and we can take a look. setting state with = will not work for rerender

Comment: @JoeLloyd  here is

Comment: you are using class components?

Comment: yes, it is obligatory to use class component

Comment: @JoeLloyd  do you have any ideo what could cause it?